# How to parse xml result received from client

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

Following code sends a request to a web service and receive the results. It successfully sends the request and show the results on console, the problem is that I can not parse the xml into object.

**Code**

```
    Request req = new Request();
    req.setLanguage(lang);

    webser webs = new webser();
    webs.setRequest(req);

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(webser.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        m.marshal(webs, os);

        WebResponse result = (WebResponse) JAXB.unmarshal(connection.getInputStream(), WebResponse.class);
        System.err.println(">>>>>>" + result.getResponse().getInfogetPersons().get(0).getId()); 
                                                      //does not return anything

        //**** populating the object manually ****
        String edd = ">";
        person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setId(1);
        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.setId(2);

        Info info = new linfo();
        info.getPersons().add(p1);
        info.gePersons().add(p2);

        Response r = new Response();
        r.setinfo(info);

        WebResponse result2 = new WebResponse();
        result2.setResponse(r);

        JAXB.marshal(result2, edd);
        System.err.println("Result:" + edd);   << does not return anything

        connection.disconnect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        return e.getMessage(); 
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
```

**WebResponse.java**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class WebResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "Response")
    private Response response = null;

    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(Response response) {
        this.response = response;
    }  
}
```

**Response.java**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Response {
   @XmlRootElement (name = "Info")
   private Info info;
   ...
}
```

**Info.java**

```
   @XmlRootElement
   public class Info {
      @XmlRootElement ( name = "Person")
      private List<Person> person;
      ....
   }
```

**Person.java**

```
   @XmlRootElement
   public class Person{

      private int Id;

      @XmlElement (name = "Id")
      public int getId() {
        return Id;
      }

      public void setId(int Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
      }
   }
```

**Actual Response from Server**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WebResponse>
      <Response target="test">
           <Info>
               <Person>
                   <Id>83094</Id>
                   <Age>34</Age>
                   <FGs>
                       <HF>0</HF>
                       <HI>1</HI>
                   </FGs>
                   <Rt>
                          <Rid parentid="412404">201735813</Rid>
                          <Rname>Special</Rname>
                          <Ca>2</Ca>
                          <link>www.google.com/test</link>
                  </Rt>
                  <Rt>
                          <Rid parentid="777777">787878</Rid>
                          <Rname>Standard</Rname>
                          <Ca>7</Ca>
                          <link>www.yahoo.com/blank</link>
                  </Rt>
             </Person>
             <Person>
               ....
              </Person>
              ......
         </Info>
         .....
```

Comment: You are not reading the inputstream twice, right?

Comment: @Leo I read it once to show its results into console and the other time to unmarshall it

Comment: @ShashankKadne there is no error the output lines which are supposed to show ">>>>>>>>>>> ....." do not show anything in console.

Comment: There must be an exception. You are returning the exception message. Are you printing it somewhere?

Comment: If there is no Exception what is going wrong...if You are able to unmarshall correctly  ..what is the need of again Parsing

Comment: @j888 no computer here to test (cellphone) but the second inputstream is not in the end of the consumed and unclosed first one, right?

Comment: @Leo would you pelase rephrase your question.

Comment: @j888 sure. What happens if you read your inputstream only once (not printing in the console for example)?

Comment: the first result shows >>>> 0

Comment: My bad. I thought getInputStream was getting a consumed stream in the second call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unmarshal directly to `List<Response>`.  You will need to unmarshal a class that has a mapped property of type `List<Response>` instead.

## UPDATE #1

Also the class you are unmarshalling needs to correspond to the level of XML you are unmarshalling.  As your code stands now you need to unmarshal to a class representing the web response.  If you want to unmarshal a sub-portion on the document you can start parsing the XML with StAX then advance the `XMLStreamReader` to the appropriate spot and unmarshal it.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

## UPDATE #2

Since you are struggling a bit, below is a model you can use.

### Java Model

**WebResponse**

If you are going to annotate the field (instance variables) then you should specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on your class (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html).

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="WebResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class WebResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "Response")
    private Response response = null;

}
```

**Response**

You can elimintate the `Info` class by using the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation to represent the grouping element (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html).

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Response {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Info")
    @XmlElement(name = "Person")
    private List<Person> person;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String target;

}
```

**Person**

You only need to use the `@XmlRootElement` on the top-level class you wish to marshal.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

    @XmlElement(name = "Id")
    private int id;

}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(WebResponse.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum21797000/input.xml");
        WebResponse wr = (WebResponse) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(wr, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WebResponse>
    <Response target="test">
        <Info>
            <Person>
                <Id>83094</Id>
            </Person>
            <Person>
                <Id>0</Id>
            </Person>
        </Info>
    </Response>
</WebResponse>
```

Comment: thanks, I created few new classes based on the structure of response but still nothing will be shown. Classes are as following WebResponse class which has a member of Response class and Response class has a list of info class.

Comment: @J888 - Try marshalling your object to XML to see what XML is being expected on the unmarshal.

Comment: @J888 - I meant to populate the object model yourself then marshal it to see what XML is being expected based on current mappings.

Comment: I populated it manually but still no result, question is updated.

Comment: @J888 - I have added a model to my answer that you can use.